# How to detect whether the app is coming from background?

Tags: android, android-activity, background-foreground

I have an app which has more than 40 activities now I want to catch the event whenever my app goes to background or coming from background. I have implemented it by keeping flags in each Activities onResume and OnPause. i would like to know is there any better way i can detect this event in the application level rather than the activity level?

Any help highly appreciated.

Thank You inadvance

Comment: onPause and onResume are intended by Google to do such work. I would stick to it if I were you.

Comment: see this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html